# Python - 2D Elastic Collision Simulation

Tags: python, beginner, animation, simulation, collision

I am currently a Python beginner, who just finished a script simulating collisions between circles (balls) in 2 dimensions.
I would appreciate comments on overall structure, variable names and really anything else.

There are bug present, such as a ball occasionally slipping out of a corner, but the code is functional
**Note**: The code is auto-formatted with 'black'
[Link to Gist](https://gist.github.com/JSogaard/187d7dc0558a929aa79c78a1272994f8)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from random import randint, uniform


class Simulation:
    def __init__(
        self, size, ball_count, max_v_factor, r_range=None, gravity=False, save=False
    ):
        self.size = size
        self.balls = []
        self.max_v_factor = max_v_factor
        self.r_range = r_range
        self.gravity = gravity
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.ax = plt.axes()
        self.save = save

        # Generate list of ball objects with random values
        for _ in range(ball_count):
            pos = np.array([randint(10, self.size - 10), randint(10, self.size - 10)])
            v = np.array(
                [
                    uniform(-size / self.max_v_factor, size / self.max_v_factor),
                    uniform(-size / self.max_v_factor, size / self.max_v_factor),
                ]
            )
            if self.r_range:
                r = uniform(self.r_range[0], self.r_range[1])
            else:
                r = size / 20

            # Calculating mass based on simplified formula for volume of sphere
            m = r ** 3

            self.balls.append(Ball(pos, m, v, r))

    def update(self):
        """Updates the positions and velocities of the balls"""
        for i, ball in enumerate(self.balls):
            ball.move(self.gravity)
            # Get ball's properties
            ball_pos, _, _, ball_r = ball.get_properties()

            for other in self.balls[i + 1 :]:
                # Get other ball's properties
                other_pos, _, _, other_r = other.get_properties()
                # Find the scalar difference between the position vectors
                diff_pos = np.linalg.norm(ball_pos - other_pos)

                # Check if the balls' radii touch. If so, collide
                if diff_pos <= ball_r + other_r:
                    ball.collide(other)

                    diff_vec = ball_pos - other_pos
                    # 'clip' is how much the balls are clipped
                    clip = ball_r + other_r - diff_pos
                    # Creating normal vector between balls
                    diff_norm = diff_vec / diff_pos
                    # Creating 'clip_vec' vector that moves ball out of the other
                    clip_vec = diff_norm * clip
                    # Set new position
                    ball.set_pos(ball_pos + clip_vec)

            # Check if the ball's coords is out of bounds
            # X-coord
            if ball_pos[0] - ball_r < 0:
                ball.bounce_x(-ball_pos[0] + ball_r)
            elif ball_pos[0] + ball_r > self.size:
                ball.bounce_x(self.size - ball_pos[0] - ball_r)

            # Y-coord
            elif ball_pos[1] - ball_r < 0:
                ball.bounce_y(-ball_pos[1] + ball_r)
            elif ball_pos[1] + ball_r > self.size:
                ball.bounce_y(self.size - ball_pos[1] - ball_r)

    def animate(self, _):
        """Updates and returns plot. To be used in Matplotlib's FuncAnimation"""

        self.ax.patches = []
        self.update()
        for ball in self.balls:
            pos, _, _, r = ball.get_properties()
            circle = plt.Circle(pos, r, color="blue")
            self.ax.add_patch(circle)

        return (self.ax,)

    def show(self):
        """Draws the table and balls"""

        self.ax.set_aspect(1)
        self.ax.set_xlim(0, self.size)
        self.ax.set_ylim(0, self.size)

        anim = animation.FuncAnimation(
            self.fig, self.animate, frames=1500, interval=5, save_count=1500
        )
        if self.save:
            writer = animation.FFMpegWriter(fps=60)
            anim.save("animation.mp4", writer=writer)
        plt.show()


class Ball:
    def __init__(self, pos, m, v, r):
        """Initialises ball with a position, mass and velocity and radius"""
        self.pos = pos
        self.m = m
        self.v = v
        self.r = r

    def move(self, gravity=False):
        """Moves ball 'v' distance."""
        if gravity:
            self.v[1] -= gravity / 20
        self.pos[0] += self.v[0]
        self.pos[1] += self.v[1]

    def collide(self, other):
        """Computes new velocities for two balls based on old velocities"""

        # Get other ball's properties
        other_pos, other_m, other_v, _ = other.get_properties()

        # Create a normal vector to the collision surface
        norm = np.array([other_pos[0] - self.pos[0], other_pos[1] - self.pos[1]])
        # Convert to unit vector
        unit_norm = norm / (np.sqrt(norm[0] ** 2 + norm[1] ** 2))
        # Create unit vector tagent to the collision surface
        unit_tang = np.array([-unit_norm[1], unit_norm[0]])

        # Project self ball's velocity onto unit vectors
        self_v_norm = np.dot(self.v, unit_norm)
        self_v_tang = np.dot(self.v, unit_tang)

        # Project other ball's velocity onto unit vectors
        other_v_norm = np.dot(other_v, unit_norm)
        other_v_tang = np.dot(other_v, unit_tang)

        # Use 1D collision equations to compute the balls' normal velocity
        self_v_prime = ((self.m - other_m) / (self.m + other_m)) * self_v_norm + (
            (2 * other_m) / (self.m + other_m)
        ) * other_v_norm

        other_v_prime = ((2 * self.m) / (self.m + other_m)) * self_v_norm + (
            (other_m - self.m) / (self.m + other_m)
        ) * other_v_norm

        # Add the two vectors to get final velocity vectors and update.
        self.v = self_v_prime * unit_norm + self_v_tang * unit_tang
        other.set_v(other_v_prime * unit_norm + other_v_tang * unit_tang)

    def bounce_x(self, distance):
        """Bounces off and edge parallel to the x axis.
        Variable, 'distance', is distance to move back out of wall"""
        self.v[0] *= -1
        self.pos[0] += distance

    def bounce_y(self, distance):
        """Bounces off and edge parallel to the x axis.
        Variable, 'distance', is distance to move back out of wall"""
        self.v[1] *= -1
        self.pos[1] += distance

    def get_properties(self):
        """Returns the position, mass and velocity and radius"""
        return self.pos, self.m, self.v, self.r

    def get_pos(self):
        """Returns the position only"""
        return self.pos

    def set_pos(self, pos):
        """Sets the new position"""
        self.pos = pos

    def set_v(self, v):
        """Sets the velocity of the ball"""
        self.v = v


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sim = Simulation(
        size=500,
        ball_count=25,
        max_v_factor=150,
        r_range=(12, 15),
        gravity=6,
        save=False,
    )
    sim.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

First, welcome to CodeReview! Second, let's tear apart your code ;-)

### Python is not Java

To me, this code reads like Java code. It's not "pythonic" in a bunch of small ways.

The most obvious is the getter/setter mentality. Python is a "consenting adult language." (Watch [Raymond Hettinger's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTLu2DFOdTg) for more.)

Instead of writing `get_foo()` and `set_foo()` just create an attribute `foo` and let users get or set it on their own. If you absolutely need to intercept those accesses later, you can use the [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=property#property) decorator to insert a method call.

### Eliminate comments!

You have a good commenting style. You are not blindly repeating the Python code in English prose. But comments are a code smell! Either you felt something was unclear, or you felt that it was inobvious.

Follow your instincts! If something is unclear or inobvious, *give it a name!* Instead of a comment like:

```
# Find the scalar difference between the position vectors
diff_pos = np.linalg.norm(ball_pos - other_pos)
```

why not write a [**helper function**](https://web.cs.wpi.edu/%7Ecs1101/a05/Docs/creating-helpers.html) or **helper method** to formally bind the description in the comment to that code?

```
def scalar_difference_between_position_vectors(a, b):
    """Return the scalar difference..."""
    return np.linalg.norm(a - b)
```

Then update your code and delete the comment:

```
diff_pos = scalar_difference_between_position_vectors(ball_pos, other_pos)
```

I'll argue that you can tidy up your code *a lot* by simply replacing your comments with functions. That includes the giant loop in `Simulation.__init__`

### Names have power

Be careful in your choice of names. Consider this line:

```
ball.move(self.gravity)
```

Seriously? What does that do? I was perfectly okay with `ball.move(` -- I totally felt like that was a good name and that I understood where you were going. I expected to see a velocity vector get passed in, or maybe an absolute destination. But why would you pass in *gravity?* Now I'm lost and uncertain. I feel like I don't understand this code at all!

Worse, when I looked up the definition, I found this:

```
def move(self, gravity=False):
    """Moves ball 'v' distance."""
    if gravity:
        self.v[1] -= gravity / 20
    self.pos[0] += self.v[0]
    self.pos[1] += self.v[1]
```

Ah, of course, `gravity` isn't something like 9.8 m/s²! It's actually a boolean... that can be divided by 20 ... What's 20?

So there are a couple of problems here. First, you need to take more care with the names you are giving functions. Instead of `ball.move` how about `ball.update` or `ball.tick` or `ball.update_position`?

I'll skip over the whole "what is gravity?" question until the next point. Instead, let's focus on 20.

`20` in this context is a [**magic number.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) And magic numbers are subject to one simple but absolute rule:

[**THERE CAN BE ONLY ONE!**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqcLjcSloXs)

And that one is `0`. Any bare number other than zero probably deserves a name. Possibly something like this:

```
TICKS_PER_SECOND = 20
```

### Use `None` to check for optional args

> Snap back to reality! Oh!
> What was `gravity`? Oh!
> That's a parameter: `False`
> Or a `bool,` you see!
> But then we divide by twenty!
> There goes @JSog', he
> Choked, he's so mad but he
> Won't give up that easy!
> No, he won't have it!

With all due respect to [Mr. Mathers](https://youtu.be/_Yhyp-_hX2s?t=75), optional parameters are simple if you treat them simply. Just use `None` and do your test using `is [not] None`:

```
def update_position(delta_t: float, gravity: Optional[float]=None):
    if gravity is not None:
        self.v[VERTICAL] -= gravity * delta_t

    self.pos[HORIZONTAL] += self.v[HORIZONTAL] * delta_t
    self.pos[VERTICAL] += self.v[VERTICAL] * delta_t
```

Don't try to rely on the equivalence between `bool` and `int` to get a zero. Just spell out the check. And even better, spell out the expected type using type annotations.